# Inner exception "index was outside the bounds.." when trying to start program

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to c# and programming in general, and was trying to build a sort of quiz in Windows Forms, where questions, answers and choices are stored in lists, and Questions, Answers and Choices are in separate classes. The Windows Forms part is four buttons and some textboxes that lets you choose which choice (1-4) you want to choose. All the lists used are of the string type btw.
But whenever I try to start the program, I am told that the TypeInitializer threw an exception. The InnerException is that the index was out of bounds.
The HResult is -2146233036, and in case it's any help, the entire StackTrace is:

> ved quizforreal.Display..ctor()
>      ved quizforreal.Program.Main() i C:\Users\Anders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\quizforreal\quizforreal\Program.cs:linje 19
>      ved System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      ved System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      ved Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      ved System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      ved System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace quizforreal
{
public partial class Display : Form
{
    int tæller = 0;
    private static Choices choiceobj = new Choices();
    private static Questions questobj = new Questions();
    private static Answers answerobj = new Answers();
    List<string> choices1list = choiceobj.getChoiceOne();
    List<string> choices2list = choiceobj.getChoiceTwo();
    List<string> choices3list = choiceobj.getChoiceThree();
    List<string> choices4list = choiceobj.getChoiceFour();
    List<string> questlist = questobj.getQuestions();
    List<string> answerlist = answerobj.getAnswers();

    public Display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
}

    public void skifter()
    {


        switch (tæller)
        {
            case 0:
                choice1.Text = choices1list[0];
                choice2.Text = choices2list[0];
                choice3.Text = choices3list[0];
                choice4.Text = choices4list[0];
                quest.Text = questlist[0];
                break;
            case 1:
                choice1.Text = choices1list[1];
                choice2.Text = choices2list[1];
                choice3.Text = choices3list[1];
                choice4.Text = choices4list[1];
                quest.Text = questlist[1];
                break;
            case 2:
                choice1.Text = choices1list[2];
                choice2.Text = choices2list[2];
                choice3.Text = choices3list[2];
                choice4.Text = choices4list[2];
                quest.Text = questlist[2];
                break;
            case 3:
                choice1.Text = choices1list[3];
                choice2.Text = choices2list[3];
                choice3.Text = choices3list[3];
                choice4.Text = choices4list[3];
                quest.Text = questlist[3];
                break;
            case 4:
                choice1.Text = choices1list[4];
                choice2.Text = choices2list[4];
                choice3.Text = choices3list[4];
                choice4.Text = choices4list[4];
                quest.Text = questlist[4];
                break;
        }
    }


    private void choice1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void choice2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void choice3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void choice4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tæller)
        {
            case 0:
                if (choice1.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (choice1.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (choice1.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (choice1.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (choice1.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tæller)
        {
            case 0:
                if (choice2.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (choice2.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (choice2.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (choice2.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (choice2.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tæller)
        {
            case 0:
                if (choice3.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (choice3.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (choice3.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (choice3.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (choice3.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tæller)
        {
            case 0:
                if (choice4.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (choice4.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (choice4.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (choice4.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (choice4.Text == answerlist[0])
                {
                    tæller++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tæller = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace quizforreal
{
public class Choices
{
    private List<string> choice1list = new List<string>();
    private List<string> choice2list = new List<string>();
    private List<string> choice3list = new List<string>();
    private List<string> choice4list = new List<string>();


    public Choices()
    {
        choice1list[0] = "mulighed1(1)";
        choice1list[1] = "mulighed1(2)";
        choice1list[2] = "mulighed1(3)";
        choice1list[3] = "mulighed1(4)";
        choice1list[4] = "mulighed1(5)";

        choice2list[0] = "mulighed2(1)";
        choice2list[1] = "mulighed2(2)";
        choice2list[2] = "mulighed2(3)";
        choice2list[3] = "mulighed2(4)";
        choice2list[4] = "mulighed2(5)";

        choice3list[0] = "mulighed3(1)";
        choice3list[1] = "mulighed3(2)";
        choice3list[2] = "mulighed3(3)";
        choice3list[3] = "mulighed3(4)";
        choice3list[4] = "mulighed3(5)";

        choice4list[0] = "mulighed4(1)";
        choice4list[1] = "mulighed4(2)";
        choice4list[2] = "mulighed4(3)";
        choice4list[3] = "mulighed4(4)";
        choice4list[4] = "mulighed4(5)";

    }

    public List<string> getChoiceOne()
    {
        return choice1list;
    }

    public List<string> getChoiceTwo()
    {
        return choice2list;
    }

    public List<string> getChoiceThree()
    {
        return choice3list;
    }

    public List<string> getChoiceFour()
    {
        return choice4list;
    }

}
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace quizforreal
{
    public class Questions
    {
        private List<string> questionslist = new List<string>();


        public Questions()
        {
            questionslist[0] = "Spørgsmål 1";
            questionslist[1] = "Spørgsmål 2";
            questionslist[2] = "Spørgsmål 3";
            questionslist[3] = "Spørgsmål 4";
            questionslist[4] = "Spørgsmål 5";
        }


        public List<string> getQuestions()
        {
            return questionslist;
        }


    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace quizforreal
{
    class Answers
    {
        private static Choices choicesobj = new Choices();
        List<string> choices1list = choicesobj.getChoiceOne();
        List<string> choices2list = choicesobj.getChoiceTwo();
        List<string> choices3list = choicesobj.getChoiceThree();
        List<string> choices4list = choicesobj.getChoiceFour();

        private List<string> answerlist = new List<string>();


        public Answers()
        {
            answerlist[0] = choices1list[0];
            answerlist[1] = choices3list[1];
            answerlist[2] = choices4list[2];
            answerlist[3] = choices1list[3];
            answerlist[4] = choices2list[4];

        }


        public List<string> getAnswers()
        {
            return answerlist;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace quizforreal
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Display());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well now, how the heck do you think we could help you find the bug in your code if there is no code for us to see?  How would that work??

Comment: You're trying to access an element in a list that doesn't exist. Debug to find out where.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that guys - I could've swore I added it

Comment: Should be there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TypeInitializer threw an exception" means that there was an error in a static constructor or field initializer.  Your form class has a static field `private static Choices choiceobj = new Choices();` Looking at your constructor for `Choices`, I see that you are trying to "add" items to a list by using an indexer, which will throw an exception if the list is not that big, so you should use `Add` instead of the indexer:

```
public class Choices
{
    private List<string> choice1list = new List<string>();
    ...

    public Choices()
    {
        choice1list.Add("mulighed1(1)");
        choice1list.Add("mulighed1(2)");
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Don't know how I missed that, I'd done it in all the constructors. I think I mix up arrays and lists sometimes. It starts now, so thank you very much :)